# Does SMBus spec lie about I2C?

Tags: i2c, smbus

In the SMBus spec it says:

> The I²C specifications do not require that a device always acknowledge its own address.
>   This can confuse a system controller.
>   If a device does not acknowledge its own address how does the system controller know if it is because the device is busy, has failed, or has been removed?

This sounds a lot like blackening I2C, and I'm not used to see this kind of language in a spec.

Besides, I think SMBus is lying here. In I2C the address byte must be acknowledged just like any other byte. Or must it?

Comment: A less contentious way to phrase this question would be just to ask about the required acknowledgement of the address byte up front.  This may get clearer answers.

Answer (score 1):

I2C does not support hot swapping so devices should not be removed. And busy devices will not acknowledge.

SMBUS does not lie, it embellished a bit, but it's not a lie. It has specs designed to improve upon actual or perceived faults in I2C.

Comment: It doesn't even appear to be an embellishment. If a device is not required to ack its address when busy, the statement is factual.